# Jenkins View Issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-cli, jenkins-pipeline

I am having issues trying to delete a view on Jenkins. I am aware it can be deleted from the sidebar simply clicking 'delete view' unfortunately in my case, delete view is not appearing and neither is the sidebar.

Is there any other way to delete a view other than, delete view on the sidebar?

Comment: Which type of view is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in the browser

https://${Jenkins-Server}:9443/view/${viewName}/delete